# Serializing on Desktop, Deserializing in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, serialization

I'm trying to create content via a small C# desktop app, and have it appear inside a Silverlight application. (I'm creating plain, ordinary C# objects, and trying to make them easily persist.) The context is a game of some sort, where I have a desktop tool that lets me create and edit the content I want, and then the Silverlight binaries consume it.

**How can I serialize something in (desktop) C# and deserialize it in Silverlight?**

I have a small library I created for serialization; it uses [Mike Talbot's amazing serializer](http://whydoidoit.com/silverlight-serializer/) for Silverlight, and a simple `BinaryFormatter` for desktop. Within each platform, these are OK; but across platforms, these two are obviously incompatible.

Is it possible to do this? I would not like to revert back to manually serializing by saving data as text and then parsing it, and I would not like to use an embedded database if possible. I may have lists of lists and other complex data, and manually parsing it is too painful.

If it's *not* possible, what alternatives do I have?

**Edit:** ProtoBuf .NET looks OK, but as I mentioned in Marc's comment, *I'm using the serializer inside my own library.* This means that requiring users of my persistence library to add attribution to classes to serialize them will break encapsulation. I don't want to do that.

What do I mean by *breaking encapsulation?*

The target user of my library (Persistent Storage) is a game developer. They will use the library to persist information within their games.

Hence, they only consume PersistentStorage.dll. Internally, Persistent Storage uses a serializer (currently, Mike Talbot's for Silverlight, and a simple Binary one for non-Silverlight) to persist data.

For me to say "to use my library, put `[ProtoContract]` or `[Serializable]` on all your classes" breaks encapsulation. It means *the user knows about the internals of my library usage,* which they shouldn't. I can change serializers tomorrow, and they shouldn't care.

I am aware that as a work-around, I can ask them to attribute everything with `[PersistMe]` and have that as a plain empty attribute that, in turn, extends whatever attribute my serializer needs. But I'm hoping that other serializers, like Mike Talbot's, will not require any attribution to use.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by breaking encapsulation? do you just not want to take a dependacy on ProtoBuf in both projects?

Comment: I have updated my question accordingly. I don't want users of my library specifying attributes that belong to an implementation detail of my library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [Silverlight Serializer](http://whydoidoit.com/silverlight-serializer/)

From the author's page:

*Serializing Classes Between **.NET 4 and Silverlight***

*You may want to use **SilverlightSerializer** to share objects between Silverlight and .NET 4, perhaps across a WCF link.
The vital thing to do in these circumstances is to define the classes you want to share in a Silverlight assembly that only references System, System.Core and mscorlib.  These are the requirements for assemblies that can be used in both types of project.  If you define your classes in this way then they can be deserialized on the back end without a problem, reference anything else and it won’t work.  Fortunately most of what you will need is included in those system assemblies!*

Comment: Maybe I missed something. I will take a look again; his actual DLL distributed doesn't have a non-Silverlight equivalent, though.

Comment: Yes, take a look - maybe it will be suited for you

Comment: It seems to be working, although it looks like I have to create a Silverlight and .NET 4 DLL with the same GUID and name and classes to make it work. Hmm ... Plus it's not (yet) recursively persisting.

Comment: I don't understand why serializers don't serialize/deserialize private fields by default, with an optional attribute to stop this behaviour. It means you have to expose EVERY field publically. Yuck; there goes my OO power and immutable classes.

Comment: ashes999 - That is pretty much what i ended up doing.  I ended up moving all my classes that will be serialized into their own projects, made sure the final assembly names and namespaces were the same in both .net and silverlight dlls.  Works fine - i also use the sharp zip lib on both server side and silverlight to make the files smaller.

Comment: Since he provides the code project, you could write your own flavor of the ISerializable interface and go that route to keep everything private ... would be alot more work though.

Comment: @Jason I'll try Marc's solution; I'm not dead-set against having everything as public type Whatever { get; set; } -- but I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same format in this scenario. Since BinaryFormatter isn't OK for Silverlight, that is out. Personally I'd use protobuf-net, which works on both and can be configured to work on vanilla objects (but is easier if you can add attributes), but if your linked serialiser works on desktop that is a viable option too.

With an example of your model I can be more specific.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. The problem is that I developed applications (games) independently on platforms, and never had the requirement of making them cross-platform until now.

Comment: @ashes999 I should add a disclaimer: I am the author of (free and OSS) protobuf-net, which is itself but a single implementation of google's cross-platform protobuf serialization format

Comment: @Marc I appreciate your honesty. Actually, I'm probably more inclined to try it now even if alternatives appear :)

Comment: Not bad, but I don't like having to annotate every field with an integer. The problem is that I'm using the serializer internally in my own library, so it's breaking encapsulation for me.

Comment: @ashes999 in v2 (available from source) you can avoid this; you will need to tell it a few things in code, though (or write some other conventions-based configuration script)

Comment: It requires annotation, which will break encapsulation for me. Cheers though.

Comment: @ashes999 no, it doesn't. I know this very well since I wrote it. In v2 you ***do not*** need to annotate.

Comment: @Marc does it automatically serialize/deserialize private fields?

Comment: @ashes999 there are various ways of configuring it; one of these is indeed field-level (public or private; similar to BinaryFormatter or DCS in implied mode) using inferred order; another is all public members (field or property; similar to XmlSerializer). A final option (my preferred) is to simply *at where-ever pleases you* tell it explicitly how to behave.

Comment: @Marc I will try it out; if it DOES automatically serialize private fields without configuration (which is ultimately what I want), I'll change my accepted answer.

Comment: @ashes you still *at some point* need to tell it what types you are working with...

Answer (score 1):

Why not try old school xml serialization with the XmlSerializer, both the .Net framework on the desktop and silverlight should have that class. This way there is no addition library to include, its in the framework.

Comment: You're right. I will try that. I prefer binary, though, because of a small layer of obfuscation of content. And because it's more compact.

Comment: also just a thought if it meets your requirements why not use compression using GZipStream in System.IO.Compression on the desktop and use small util in silverlight to decompress. small and lightweight :) http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2009/04/21/REALLY-small-unzip-utility-for-Silverlight.aspx

Comment: The problem is that everything needs to be compatible. I would be potentially zipping in a desktop app and unzipping in Silverlight. This is the crux of my difficulty. But yes, XML seems like a decent idea.

Comment: This requires everything in my class to be public. That will break encapsulation on too many levels.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at [**Sharp serializer**](http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/tutorial/index.html). It allows you to either **use xml based formatting or binary formatting** for serialization.

I have used it in a similar scenario to share data between a Silverlight and a non Silverlight application and it works beautifully.

Comment: How did you make it de-serialize? It's telling me that the assembly of my type is conflicting; I have two DLLs, one for .NET 4 and one for Silverlight, that have the same class definitions in them. (Serialize in .NET 4, deserialize in Silverlight.)

Comment: I need to know how to make a DLL with the classes that will work both on Desktop and in Silverlight.

Comment: Nice, but doesn't automatically serialize/deserialize private fields.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference:

- you can build a single SilverlightSerializer DLL and reference it in .net and Silverlight. this works even though the DLL targets Silverlight
- Silverlight doesn't run with enough security permissions to enable the inspection of private class members. SilverlightSerializer let's you write support classes to serialize third party components with non-standard requirements, and this can work for private members, but in that particular case it's manual and requires that the serialization class and the serialized class are one in the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a JSON Serializer like JSON.net ( http://json.codeplex.com/ )?

JSON Specification: http://json.org

Comment: Nope. What are the advantages over the plain old XML one?

Comment: The resulting string is much smaller (saves bandwidth + speed) and better to read (if you have to - debugging). We use JSON for all serialization work in our app and it works really well. Also I like the format because its syntax is dead simple so you can spot mistakes fast (specification: http://json.org/). XML can get quite unwieldy fast.

Answer (score 0):

We use WCF to do all our serialization to the Silverlight client.  We have a dll shared between the client and the server that has all the data transfer objects and interfaces.  This allows us to not use the wsdl to generate service ref in silverlight.

To do the searlization we use the DataContractSerializer with a BinaryMessageEncoding.  Also you do have to watch out for private setters of objects (which cant be done in silverlight, as you cant set a property with a private setter in the partial trust enviroment of silverlight).  If you want to use generics and other things like that, use the NetDataContractSerializer, but that will break compatability with Java and other standards based web services outside of .net (but should work fine for silverlight).

All our DTO's are POCO, other then we add a [ItemKey] Attribute to one of the properties (no other attributes or interfaces), so that our system knows which property is the primary key  (this isnt required but it makes things easier to do updates in the persistance layer if things change in the objects).